# How to convert bs4.element.Tag to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I want to parse only text from blogspot and do as bellow

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("https://edwvb.blogspot.ru/2018/03/3-tipa-povedeniya-kotorye-opredelyayut-uspeshnyh-prodavcov.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

so I can see just this way to pars text of the post

```
nameList = bsObj.findAll("div", {"dir":"ltr", "style":"text-align: left;", "trbidi":"on"})
```

But by this I parse two objects and when I convert this to pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(nameList)
```

I get two rows.

```
                   0
0   \n\n\n\n\n(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle ||...
1   \nПеревод статьи 3 Behaviors That Drive Succes...
```

I need parse just row 1. I try to do like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(nameList[1])
```

and get

```
TypeError: DataFrame constructor called with incompatible data and dtype: setting an array element with a sequence
```

nameList[1] has type bs4.element.Tag

```
  type(nameList[1])
  bs4.element.Tag
```

so how to convert bs4.element.Tag to pandas? Or may be there is more easy way to parse text blogspot.com?

Comment: Do you just want the text associated with the tag? Your variable `namelist` will return a list of tags, therefore the two rows in your converted `DataFrame` is the expected behavior.

Comment: @rahlf23 I remove tags by `df[0].apply(lambda x: (re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', str(x))))`

Comment: Just simply use: `namelist = [i.text for i in namelist]` (this assumes that `namelist` is not `None`) prior to converting to `DataFrame`

Comment: I again get two rows I need remove `'\n\n\n\n\n(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's may be not an easy decision

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://edwvb.blogspot.ru/2018/03/3-tipa-povedeniya-kotorye-opredelyayut-uspeshnyh-prodavcov.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

nameList = bsObj.findAll("div", {"dir":"ltr", "style":"text-align: left;", "trbidi":"on"})
nameList = [i.text for i in nameList]
```

After that we need first convert `nameList[1]` to `pd.Series` and then to `DataFrame`

```
S = pd.Series(nameList[1])
S.to_frame()
```